# Прервал команду mv. Последствия?

Tags: linux

С помощью команды **mv** перемешал файл, размером более 450 ГБ, в другую директорию. Перемещение прервалось. Подскажите, в этом случае исходный файл остается неизменным?

Comment: А команда `ls -l` для обеих каталогов что говорит?

Comment: Да, исходный файл, скорее всего, не поменялся. Не делайте `mv` между дисками, делайте `cp`. Если файл большой, запаситесь его контрольной суммой, проверьте её после копирования.

Comment: Если `mv` исполняется долго, это значит что файл перемещается между различными файловыми системами. В этом случае под капотом работает `cp`, в случае успеха исходный файл удаляется. Так что всё у вас хорошо.

Comment: Благодарю. У меня произошел сбой в bash-скрипте и команда mv начала выполняться несвоевременно.  По этой причине пришлось завершить работу mv и тем самым не был понятен вопрос целостности исходного файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно почитать первоисточник

[11.4 mv: Move (rename) files](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mv-invocation.html)

> To move a file, mv ordinarily simply renames it. However, if renaming
> does not work because the destination’s file system differs, mv falls
> back on copying as if by cp -a, then (assuming the copy succeeded) it
> removes the original. If the copy fails, then mv removes any partially
> created copy in the destination. If you were to copy three directories
> from one file system to another and the copy of the first directory
> succeeded, but the second didn’t, the first would be left on the
> destination file system and the second and third would be left on the
> original file system.

яндекс перевод

> Чтобы переместить файл, `mv` обычно просто переименовывает его.
> Однако, если переименование не работает из-за различий в файловой
> системе получателя, `mv` возвращается к копированию, как если бы с
> помощью `cp -a`, затем (при условии, что копирование завершилось
> успешно) удаляет оригинал. Если копирование завершается неудачно, то
> `mv` удаляет любую частично созданную копию в пункте назначения. Если
> бы вы скопировали три каталога из одной файловой системы в другую и
> копия первого каталога была выполнена успешно, а второго - нет, первый
> был бы оставлен в целевой файловой системе, а второй и третий были бы
> оставлены в исходной файловой системе.

если кратко, то с вашим исходным файлом всё в порядке